# How to uninstall this Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, uninstall, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed [Chrome Lock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ofilhkhdoiamdkbgciniekmdgjehaadm/):

[image]

However it keeps crashing all the time.

[image]

I wanted to uninstall it, but to my surprise, it is not listed in the Chrome Extensions [`chrome://extensions/`] page.

**What should I do to fix this (remove Chrome Lock)?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If your extensions are not listed,
>   they can be uninstalled by deleting
>   them. This can be done by finding out
>   where your extensions are installed in
>   your computer. You can find these from
>   your Chrome profile or you can search
>   them manually in your Documents and
>   Settings folder.

http://pcsplace.com/google/how-to-use-google-chrome-extensions-enable-install-remove-uninstall/

Comment: Where do I find my Chrome Profile?

Comment: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Just make sure you label this as answered.